# need to print exceptions in a single line and filter data based on search string and timestamp

Tags: awk

I am very new to awk command and is learning.
I have a requirement as below.

- Need to read a log file
- Search for a string in it
- Search should be based on the timestamp

Sample Log (Actual):

```
INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:39.253 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt1 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:39.254 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt2 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:39.255 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt3 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

ERROR 2018-03-07 04:06:39.825 [xyzxyzxyz] [SocketConsole] No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[XXXXXXXXXX]' 

with instance id
com.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.client.abcdefghij: No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[xxxxxxxxxxx]' 
with instance id
        at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.core.impl.AppServicesManagerImpl.searchApps(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.java:205)

INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:41.253 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt4 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

WARN 2018-03-07 04:06:42.825 [xyzxyzxyz] [SocketConsole] No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[XXXXXXXXXX]' 

with instance id
com.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.client.abcdefghij: No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[xxxxxxxxxxx]' 

with instance id
        at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.core.impl.AppServicesManagerImpl.searchApps(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.java:205)
```

Expected:

```
INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:39.253 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt1 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:39.254 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt2 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:39.255 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt3 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

ERROR 2018-03-07 04:06:39.825 [xyzxyzxyz] [SocketConsole] No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[XXXXXXXXXX]' with instance idcom.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.client.abcdefghij: No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[xxxxxxxxxxx]' with instance id at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.core.impl.AppServicesManagerImpl.searchApps(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.java:205)

INFO 2018-03-07 04:06:41.253 [xyzxyzxyz] [abcdefgh] logstatemnt4 Connected successfully to client at 'xxx.x.x.x:x,xxx'

WARN 2018-03-07 04:06:42.825 [xyzxyzxyz] [SocketConsole] No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[XXXXXXXXXX]' with instance idcom.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.client.abcdefghij: No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[xxxxxxxxxxx]' with instance id at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.core.impl.AppServicesManagerImpl.searchApps(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.java:205)
```

Note: the is NO extra newline after every log statement
I am using below command to search a string based on the search text and the timestamp

```
awk '$0 ~ "No matching instances found" && $2 " " $3 > "2018-03-07 04:06:42.82" { print $0 }' /xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx-xxxxx/logs/file.log
```

This is working fine if the log statements are printed on a single line, However for the logs that contains exception as new line, it is giving all the instances of search text in the log

I would really appreciate if you can also explain the solution that you provide for my learning purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk -v RS='[A-Z]+ [0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+' '{split(rt,sDate," ");} rt $0 ~ "No matching instances found" && sDate[2] " " sDate[3]> "2018-03-07 04:06:42.82" {print rt $0} {rt=RT}' file

RT gives you the text as 'WARN 2018-03-07 04:06:42.825'. Split the RT from " " and then use the date and time to compare

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

One comment up front. If there are no extra newlines in your file don't post the log with

> Sample Log (Actual):

and add a disclaimer afterwards.  That is time consuming for the people trying to offer you a solution.

If you use `gawk` with multi-char RS support, it's easy.

```
$ awk -v RS='[A-Z]+ [0-9:.-]+' '
        /No matching instances found/ && $2" "$3 > "2018-03-07 04:06:42.82"
              {print rt $0} {rt=RT}' file

ERROR 2018-03-07 04:06:39.825 [xyzxyzxyz] [SocketConsole] No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[XXXXXXXXXX]'
with instance id
com.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.client.abcdefghij: No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[xxxxxxxxxxx]'
with instance id
        at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.core.impl.AppServicesManagerImpl.searchApps(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.java:205)

WARN 2018-03-07 04:06:42.825 [xyzxyzxyz] [SocketConsole] No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[XXXXXXXXXX]'
with instance id
com.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.client.abcdefghij: No matching instances found. Compared the given criteria(s) '[xxxxxxxxxxx]'
with instance id
        at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.core.impl.AppServicesManagerImpl.searchApps(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.java:205)
```

here need to capture the record separator to a variable since normally it tags the end of record, but we treat as the beginning of a record; so we have to lag one.

Comment: Thanks @karakfa for the reply. I tweaked the above command as below to serve my purpose
awk -v RS='[A-Z]+ [0-9-]+ [0-9:.]+' '{split(rt,sDate," ");} rt $0 ~ "No matching instances found" && sDate[2] " " sDate[3]> "2018-03-07 04:06:42.82" {print rt $0} {rt=RT}' file